# Methods to prevent abuse of a web api

Tags: api, networking, server, backend

I am developing an android game and I wanted to add leaderboard. So bought a vps and wrote a node js program that works like this.

IPAddress/fetchleaderboardinfo - sends back leaderboard

IPAdress/changeplayervalue?name=player&value=20 - changes player score

My problem is any data sniffer can see that my app is sending those requests. So anyone can just send changeplayervalue request in a browser and change their score.

How can I prevent this?

Comment: You can use https instead of http which would counter the sniffing problem. Another option is to use signed json web token which means people can see your request but wouldn't be able to generate a new valid token or change your token.

Comment: Some applications still can sniff https by installing a certificate but json approach sounds really good. Thanks